# Launch minecraft with cli

Tags: java, bash, minecraft

I try to launch Minecraft from terminal, and i have a problem, the access token isn't recognize the arg of command (offline account but token is required)

I have made a bash script to launch it with dependencies

The logs :

```
2024-02-29 17:08:56,173 main ERROR Error processing element Queue ([Appenders: null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND
2024-02-29 17:08:56,475 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "ServerGuiConsole" for logger config "root"
Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.MissingRequiredOptionException: Missing required option(s) ['accessToken']
    at joptsimple.OptionParser.ensureRequiredOptions(OptionParser.java:375)
    at joptsimple.OptionParser.parse(OptionParser.java:365)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:53)
```

I'm newer at java and i don't have good level in java, my script :

```
#!/bin/bash
command='/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.library.path=native/ -cp minecraft-1.8.9-client.jar:joptsimple.jar:lwjgl.jar:lwjgl_util.jar:guava-17.0.jar:log4j-api.jar:log4j-core.jar:gson-2.8.2.jar:commons-lang3.jar net.minecraft.client.main.Main --username Lodak --version 1.8.9 --gameDir ./.minecraft --assetsDir ./assets --assetIndex 1.8 --uuid --accessToken e0e1c613a7634006aaa50a4783ddc6bd --userProperties --userType Offline'
echo "SH Script command : $command"
$command
```

And the last question, why this line is here with ServerGuiConsole for the client jar : `2024-02-29 17:08:56,475 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "ServerGuiConsole" for logger config "root"`

Thank you for your time, have a good day

OpenJDK 8 Minecraft 1.8.9 AMD3015e x86_64 CPU Linux 6.7.4 custom build Ubuntu 24.04 Noble Numbat (dev branch)

I have use the PolyMC minecraft jar, assets and linux natives

For other jar files is directly download with good version for 1.8.9

The accessToken used is an offline token randomly generated by PolyMC, used for the test, so you cannot use this same to login MSA auth, because it's a random token

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which arguments the PolyMC jar requires, but a good way to find out is to launch it (from the normal PolyMC launcher), and follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/405041) to get the launch command.
I can't say that I've tried using said answer, but if it doesn't work just find a way to 'get the launch command of an application'.
There, you ought to see exactly which arguments you need to provide to launch it yourself.

As for the Minecraft arguments (also included in that command), you can find the arguments and libraries required in json form by looking at '.minecraft/versions/version_manifest_v2.json'.
There, it has the urls to every version of the game.

I hope this helps at least a little!